# I want to use href to decide which modal needs to be toggled open

Tags: angular, href

I have two modal with `id="detailsModal"` and `id="messageModal"`. Depending on the response I receive from the backend, I set the value for errorMessage which in case of no error is null. Depending on this, I wish to decide the href. I have used the following code to do so, but it is not working.

```
href="{{errorMessage === null ? '#detailsModal' : '#messageModal'}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with ng-template and NgIf. https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

You can do this with your error:

```
<div *ngIf="errorMessage === null; then thenBlock; else elseBlock">this is ignored</div>
<ng-template #thenBlock>Then text to show</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Else text to show</ng-template>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But, I am using the same modal to display multiple errors, so I won't be able to use this for my purpose.